# How to use BarcodeScanner plugin from NativeScript-vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, qr-code, barcode-scanner, nativescript-vue

I am a beginner in NativeScript and need to scan a QR code. I tried to use the nativescript-barcodescanner plug-in with Vue.js and I couldn't, an error occurred while running all the demos. I tried to find examples, but I found nothing to help me.

I wrote this code based on the demo-vue, but it also didn't work:

```html
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="BarcodeScanner demo"></ActionBar>

        <StackLayout>
            <Button text="back camera" @tap="doScanWithBackCamera"></Button>
            <BarcodeScanner
                row="1"
                height="300"
                formats="QR_CODE, EAN_13, UPC_A"
                beepOnScan="true"
                reportDuplicates="true"
                preferFrontCamera="false"
                @scanResult="onScanResult">
            </BarcodeScanner>

        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    var BarcodeScanner = require("nativescript-barcodescanner").BarcodeScanner;

    export default {
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            onScanResult(evt) {
                console.log(`onScanResult: ${evt.text} (${evt.format})`);
            },
            doScanWithBackCamera() {
                this.scan();
            },
            scan() {
                var barcodescanner = new BarcodeScanner();
                barcodescanner.scan({
                cancelLabel: "EXIT. Also, try the volume buttons!", // iOS only, default 'Close'
                cancelLabelBackgroundColor: "#333333", // iOS only, default '#000000' (black)
                message: "Use the volume buttons for extra light", // Android only, default is 'Place a barcode inside the viewfinder rectangle to scan it.'
                showFlipCameraButton: true,   // default false
                showTorchButton: true,        // iOS only, default false
                resultDisplayDuration: 500,   // Android only, default 1500 (ms), set to 0 to disable echoing the scanned text
                beepOnScan: true,             // Play or Suppress beep on scan (default true)
                openSettingsIfPermissionWasPreviouslyDenied: true, // On iOS you can send the user to the settings app if access was previously denied
                closeCallback: () => {
                    console.log("Scanner closed @ " + new Date().getTime());
                }
                }).then(
                    function (result) {
                    console.log("--- scanned: " + result.text);
                    // Note that this Promise is never invoked when a 'continuousScanCallback' function is provided
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // if this alert doesn't show up please upgrade to {N} 2.4.0+
                        alert({
                        title: "Scan result",
                        message: "Format: " + result.format + ",\nValue: " + result.text,
                        okButtonText: "OK"
                        });
                    }, 500);
                    },
                    function (errorMessage) {
                    console.log("No scan. " + errorMessage);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
  ActionBar {
    background-color: #53ba82;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
</style>
```

The error to build demo-vue is:

```sh
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\demo-vue\tsconfig.json
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) C:/NativeScript/nativescript-barcodescanner-master/src/barcodescanner.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner.ts(2,59)
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2307: Cannot find module 'tns-core-modules/application'.
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) C:/NativeScript/nativescript-barcodescanner-master/src/barcodescanner.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner.ts(3,28)
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2307: Cannot find module 'tns-core-modules/application'.
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) C:/NativeScript/nativescript-barcodescanner-master/src/barcodescanner.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner.ts(4,24)
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2307: Cannot find module 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils'.
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts(1,29)
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2307: Cannot find module 'tns-core-modules/ui/content-view'.
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts(2,26)
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2307: Cannot find module 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/properties'.
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts(3,34)
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2307: Cannot find module 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base'.
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI) [tsl] ERROR in C:\NativeScript\nativescript-barcodescanner-master\src\barcodescanner-common.ts(199,42)
[20-05-06 11:10:12.631] (CLI)       TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.
[20-05-06 11:10:13.831] Build failed. Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
```

I would like someone to explain to me how to use the plugin, else if someone has an example that can help me, else if they know another plugin that is easier to use.

Comment: Did you register the element as described in docs? What error you are getting?

Comment: [20-05-05 17:05:27.098] Build failed. Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.

Comment: We would need complete error log not just last line.

Comment: if I try build the project, the error is only that.

Comment: You can not use barcode scanner plugin with Preview app, you should build the app.

Answer (score 0):

## Vue version of BarcodeScanner demo.

**The main problem is: the demo is for old version of nativescript**

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner/tree/master/demo-vue

> The current application is not compatible with NativeScript CLI 6.0.
>   Use the `tns migrate` command to migrate the app dependencies to a
>   form compatible with NativeScript 6.0.

Run `tns migrate` then `tns doctor`

tns doctor will say: *Update available for component tns-core-modules.*

Remove platforms and reinstall

```sh
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
```

#### your package.json file it should include

`"nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.4.2",`

Run  `tns debug android --no-hmr` and check your console for errors.

---

### For a fresh start you should always prefer :

1.Starting the nativescript-vue project using [quick start](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/)

2. Install Plugin using `npm i nativescript-barcodescanner` or `yarn add nativescript-barcodescanner`
3. Add the following line to your **main.ts** file. (after all import lines)

```js
Vue.registerElement('BarcodeScanner', () => require('nativescript-barcodescanner').BarcodeScannerView)
```

4. Use [App.vue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner/blob/master/demo-vue/app/components/App.vue) file from vue demo project

Comment: thanks man, but now another error occurred to create the application in debug mode, I replaced the error in the question

Comment: Share your repository. These are all installation errrors. You better use `tns doctor`and `tns info`.  for example for : TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. use npm install @types/node --save